# How to open Electron-based application using Nightwatch framework?

Tags: selenium, electron, nightwatch.js, webdriver-io

I am looking to automate electron based application, using nightwatch.js

I tried to do it using Java/Selenium but did not succeeded as I was able to open application but not able to perform any action after opening.

Now I read about Nightwatch JS which uses webdriverIO which can help us automate web based applications.

As Electron app is window based application which opens web view in it so thinking of using it.

Comment: Or if anybody has done with spectron can may be help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do the same and have uploaded a sample project in Github for reference at https://github.com/rik12s/ElectronApp-Automation-Nightwatch.git